# how to load binary image from database to imagebox.imageurl in asp.net(NO MVC) using entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

i have already searched but could not find the proper answer. see the below code and tell me what to do. the name of my imagebox is picbox
  thanks in advance

```
try
{
int w = Convert.ToInt32(RegID.Text);
byte[] image = null;
{
var photoRecord = (from accom in re.Students
                    where accom.RegistrationNo == w
                    select accom).First();
image = photoRecord.Picture;

}

}
catch (Exception)
{
throw;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting a compile error or a runtime error? What type is `photoRecord`? There is not enough information to answer this question.

Comment: @default.kramer I appreciate your effort but r.hamad has answered my question and it just worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have added only two lines and it must perfectly work

```
try
{
int w = Convert.ToInt32(RegID.Text);
byte[] image = null;
{
var photoRecord = (from accom in re.Students
                where accom.RegistrationNo == w
                select accom).First();
image = photoRecord.Picture;
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(image, 0, image.Length);
picbox.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
}
}
catch (Exception)
{
throw;
}
```